# javascript - Replace " ." with "." to eliminate spaces before dots

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, whitespace

I've tried with `replace(/ ./g,  '.');` to eliminate the comma before the dot without succes.
Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume your complaint is that every character followed by a space is being replaced with a `.`. This is because `.` is a wildcard character. Literally, it means "match anything except a newline":

> (The dot, the decimal point) matches any single character except the newline characters: `\n \r \u2028` or `\u2029`. [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)

You need to escape it if you want to match a literal `.`:

```
replace(/ \./g, '.')
```

Comment: And how is it if theese comas and dots are repeated, like  . . . .
Thanks

Comment: @zsola3075457 `". . . .".replace(/ \./g, '.')` gives `....`. Is this not what you want?

Answer (score 3):

The `.` is a special character, you should escape it:

```
" .bla".replace(/ \./g, '.');
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are presenting the dot `.` means `match any single character` (except newline), the dot `.` is considered a special character in regular expressions and needs to be escaped.

I would tack on a quantifier also with matching the whitespace before the dot so it replaces all occurrences.

```
str = str.replace(/\s+\./g, '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `string = string.replace(/\s\./, '.');`?

Comment: Yes, this solution it is better if I have more than 1 spaces before  dot, by changing the \s to \s+. Thanks